# make homepage of site with page available in site assets

Tags: site, homepage

I have a `home.aspx` page in my Site Assets, which I want to show as homepage of my team site.. is this possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a SharePoint page then yes, you can make that page as your Homepage by clicking the "Make Homepage" option on the ribbon menu.

Just open that home.aspx, then click page option on ribbon and then click Make HomePage option then your landing page will change to home.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. follow below steps to achieve this:

1. Open your page.
2. Click on "PAGE" from ribbon at the top.
3. Click on "Make Homepage" from "Page Actions" section.

it will set your page as a homepage for site.

Comment: have you tried this?